# Mailchimp, send_mail() via Django, Open rate tracking

Tags: django, sendmail, mailchimp, django-email

I am deciding whether to send emails via Mailchimp or Django.

My email templates are quite basic, and the mail-merge (with various fields specific to user) could be easily done in the Django template system

The pros of Mailchimp are - tracking open rates, and click rates

Pros of Django email is : Mailchimp email lands up in the Social Tab in Gmail and equivalent of other email providers (shows up as From : myadmin@mydomain.com via xxx.mailchimp.com, and this last bit makes Gmail put it in Social), while emails from Django are always from myadmin@mydomain.com.

Is there a package to integrate tracking open rates in Django send_mail()?

Answer (score 0):

If you have dedicated server and in the help of postfix you can email from `email@domain.com`

but `mailchimp, Mandrill, SendGrid` all are provide that kind of service when you are pay to them.